# Play framework reads assets file in unmanagedResourceDirectories

Tags: playframework, sbt, assets, production

[image]
I ran into a problem of reading a file in `unmanagedResourceDirectories` generated by Webpack in production mode. Given the following snippet:

```
  val manifest: Try[JsValue] = Try(Json.parse(
    Source.fromFile(new File("/public/manifest.json")).getLines.mkString
  ))
```

I want to read sth like `/public/manifest.json`.

Answer (score 1):

I manage to find the solution for it. Add this to `build.sbt`

```
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Assets += (baseDirectory.value / "js-frontend" / "build"),
mappings in Universal ++= directory(baseDirectory.value / "js-frontend" / "build" / "manifest.json"),
```

And I can have sth like this in code:

```
val manifest: Try[JsValue] = Try(Json.parse(
  Source.fromFile(env.getFile("/manifest.json")).getLines.mkString
))
```